# How to create a partition table from data of an already present table in bigquery using webui query?

Tags: google-bigquery

create or replace table test.sourav_part_test_1 partition by DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) as select *, _PARTITIONTIME as pt from `test.sourav`

showing error: "Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME at [1:66]"
i need the partition column name as _PARTITIONTIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#partition_expression

> PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) — partitions the table using the date-based timestamp in the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column. **This syntax is only supported with CREATE TABLE without the AS query_statement clause**.

Comment: Instead, you can use a CREATE TABLE statement followed by an INSERT statement as a workaround.